# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ‘mvc.Models.ModelA’ but this dictionary requires a model item of type ‘mvc.Models.ModelB‘

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, build

I have this annoying mistake in some of my builds.

There is no error in the project, because if I build again, then the problem disappears. The message only appears, when the site is deployed to a Windows 2008 Server.

I first  thought that it might be an issue with temporary files, but thats not the case. I deployed the build to a different web and the error still appears.

The error appears on random actions of the site. Most of the time builds are ok, but each 3rd or 4th build produces runtime errors.

I build using a WebdeploymentProject in release mode. Views are precompiled.

It's not [In ASP.NET MVC I encounter an incorrect type error when rendering a page with the correct typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178194/in-asp-net-mvc-i-encounter-an-incorrect-type-error-when-rendering-a-page-with-the), because views have totally different names.

How I can debug this problem or how I can get help for this?

Here is my WebDeploymentProject

```
    <!-- 
      Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Web Deployment Project 
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=104956

    -->
    <Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{E5E14CEB-0BCD-4203-9A5A-34ABA9C717EA}</ProjectGuid>
        <SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\B2CWeb</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
        <SourceWebProject>{3E632DB6-6DB3-4BD0-8CCA-12DE67165B48}|B2CWeb\B2CWeb.csproj</SourceWebProject>
        <SourceWebVirtualPath>/B2CWeb.csproj</SourceWebVirtualPath>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <OutputPath>.\Debug</OutputPath>
        <EnableUpdateable>false</EnableUpdateable>
        <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
        <SingleAssemblyName>B2CWeb_Build</SingleAssemblyName>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
        <OutputPath>..\B2CWeb_Deploy\</OutputPath>
        <EnableUpdateable>false</EnableUpdateable>
        <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
        <SingleAssemblyName>B2C_Web</SingleAssemblyName>
        <ContentAssemblyName>
        </ContentAssemblyName>
        <DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>false</DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
      </ItemGroup>
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets" />
      <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
           Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets.
      <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      </Target>
      <Target Name="BeforeMerge">
      </Target>
      <Target Name="AfterMerge">
      </Target>
      <Target Name="AfterBuild">
      </Target>
      -->
    </Project>
```

**EDIT**

After some months this problem disapeared. I haven't had problems for over 1 year now. I guess the issue will strike again when nobody expects it.

**EDIT 2**

… for over 2 years now. I am such a lucky dude!

**EDIT 3**

I just read [an article on MSDN](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications/), and it sounds like the problem I had. I have debugging disabled, but still the compilation was "sometimes wrong". The behaviour of the old provider could be the issue. But this is just guessing.

> Very large pages containing long spans of HTML with no server blocks (e.g. <%= %>) can cause a stack overflow when debug compilation is enabled that will crash the application. Note that in our testing it’s taken a page that’s ~4x as large one that would’ve produced a similar issue in the old provider, but in this case it crashes the entire application, whereas with the old provider it just fails the offending page

Comment: Can you confirm it has something to do with the build process? It sounds more like a coding bug to me. Did you try tracing the exception?

Comment: Can provide the stack trace and the piece of code at the site of the exception?

Comment: @Johannes: It realy is an issue of the build process. I do clean checkouts of the sources. I know this is hard to believe...

Comment: the problem still here

Answer (score 175):

Even if the types match, you can get this error when a null is passed to a partial view.

You can fix this by calling `RenderPartial` with an empty `ViewDataDictionary` like this:

```
helper.RenderPartial("~/Views/Player/PlayerName.ascx", player, new ViewDataDictionary());
```

For reference, I found this solution at:
[renderpartial with null model gets passed the wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650393/asp-net-mvc-renderpartial-with-null-model-gets-passed-the-wrong-type)

Comment: If I have a build that is not ok, then any data passed to the View results in the error.

Comment: "You can get this error when a null is passed to a partial view" -- bingo, fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: The details why it does that are explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1049170/187650

Answer (score 14):

### ASP.NET MVC Partials

NULL model was passed!!!

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView", model: Model)
```

Comment: This is so annoying, I might just migrate to the LAMP stack out of protest!

Comment: @series0ne don't be so desperate, just make sure your model is not null :)

Answer (score 7):

This error can occur (and does) when there is a mismatch between the data that the controller action method is supplying to the view and the type of data the view is expecting.  This will not normally show up as a build error, even with precompiled views.

For example, if I have a method...

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Do something
    return View(new CustomerCreateViewModel());
}
```

...and a Create view with a Page attribute...

```
<%@ Page ... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CustomerDetailsViewModel>" %>
```

...this will compile and build without error. However, when I call the Create action, I'm going to get a yellow screen, because the Create action method is throwing data of one type and the view is expecting data of a different type. You might want to verify that your types are matching...

Comment: Your explanantion is definitily right. But my problem is that some build are ok and others not, even with the same source.

Answer (score 3):

Are you *absolutely* sure that this has nothing to do with the data being passed to the view? Are you performing a full rebuild each time?

These errors typically occur because a partial view tries to use the view model passed to the ViewPage when the view model passed to the partial view is null. I realize that you are implying that the error is somehow caused by the build process, but I don't see how that would be possible. 
Could it be that the deployed site uses a different database than the site you run on your development machine, and could the data (or lack of data) in that database be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Its realy the build. If I rebuild and leave everything as it is, then the error desapears...or appears on a different action

Answer (score 2):

Do the build trigger any warnings or errors at all?

Do you have your dependencies set up correctly? Eg. views depending on models. Build figures out in what order to compile things by looking at the dependencies specified. Eg. if you change a model and the view is compiled before the model you get into trouble...

Do this disappear if you don't compile views?

Also do your views inherit `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` or `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<T>` where T is your model?

Comment: Do this disappear if you don't compile views?

Thats something I will try...Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Before assigning the model to the usercontrol from your view, instantiate that particular object in the constructor of the Model/Entity.

Example:

```
 public class MainEntity
 {
    public SubEntity AssociatedEntity;

    public MainEntity()
    {
        // This is where the instantiation happen.
        AssociatedEntity = new SubEntity(); 
    }
 }

 public class SubEntity
 {
    public string property1;
 }
```

Your View Page :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNamespace.Models.MainEntity>" %>
....
<%Html.RenderPartial("ucMyUserControl",Model.AssociatedEntity);
....
```

Your User Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyNamespace.Models.SubEntity>" %>
....
<%Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Property1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an overriding **Views** folder, where multiple partials of the same name exist (one overriding another with the same name), be sure to update the Model type on each view or you might receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following error message

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[MyProject.Models.A,MyProject.Models.B]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List1[MyProject.Models.B]'.

with the following code

```
IEnumerable<B> list_B;
...
IEnumerable<A> list_A = Repo.GetListOfType_A();
list_B = list_A.Select(x => new B { Number = x.Number, Name = x.Name });
...
return View(list_B);
```

and I have no idea what was the type

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[MyProject.Models.A,MyProject.Models.B]

anyway, the error goes away when I add a `.ToList()` at the end

```
IEnumerable<B> list_B;
...
IEnumerable<A>list_A = Repo.GetListOfType_A();
list_B = list_A.Select(x => new B { Number = x.Number, Name = x.Name }).ToList(); // here
...
return View(list_B);
```

Hope it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by a silly cut and paste error in my context.  I was getting this error on my Contact index.

```
    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Contact { get; set; }
    // Note this ^^^^^^^^ should have been Contact
```

It compiled okay, but gave me the error when trying to render the view.

(Adding this as something else for future people looking for solutions to try.)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while using Episerver. I simply changed the return statement in the controller from 
`return View();`

to

`return PartialView();`